# chrome extension - how does Zenhub sync data with other members in the same repo?

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, github-api, zenhub

I am making an extension for github. And I want to sync data with other people at the same repo.

For example, in Zenhub, the pipelines of a board is synced automatically with other members. In other words, if I remove `Back log`, other members can't see the `Back log` pipeline in their board.
[image]

How can I implement that? I can't find any answers about this.

Comment: Inspect zenhub's code.

Comment: @wOxxOm Where can I inspect zenhub code? Is it an open source?

Comment: Any extension is a bunch of javascript which you can inspect and debug in the browser. This is basically the same as inspecting and debugging your own extension so there are tons of tutorials.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you!